# How to bake rigidbody simulation from commandline?

Tags: baking, rigid-body-simulation, command-line

How to bake rigidbody simulation from commandline?

I want to run simulation from cloud services, which are head-less. So I want to run from command-line. I searched around for a while, and tried various approaches such as:

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    print(area.type)
    if area.type == 'PROPERTIES':
        print('dir(area.spaces)', dir(area.spaces))
        for name, space in area.spaces.items():
            print(name, space)
        print('area.spaces[0]', area.spaces[0])
        sp = area.spaces[0]
        print('dir(sp)', dir(sp))
        print('sp.context', sp.context)
        print('area.spaces.active', area.spaces.active)
        print('area.spaces[0]', area.spaces[0])
        print('area.spaces.active == area.spaces[0]', area.spaces.active == area.spaces[0])
        active_space = area.spaces.active
        active_space.context = 'SCENE'
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        override["area"] = area
        print('override', override)
        for k, v in override.items():
            print('    ', k, v)
        # bg = space_data.background_images.new()
        # bg.image = img
        with bpy.context.temp_override(**override):
            # bpy.context.space_data.context = 'SCENE'
            print('area', bpy.context.area, bpy.context.area.type, bpy.context.area.ui_type, dir(bpy.context.area))
            print('space_data', bpy.context.space_data, bpy.context.space_data.type, bpy.context.space_data.context, dir(bpy.context.space_data))
            print('scene', bpy.context.scene, bpy.context.scene.name)
            bpy.ops.ptcache.bake(bake=True)
        break
```

... but could not figure out how to set the context correctly. How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Create a script `bake_ptcache.py` like:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.ptcache.bake_all(bake=True)
bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()
```

Then run like:

```
/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender \
     --background \
    ~/BlenderFiles/test_render1.blend \
    --python bake_ptcache.py
```

Notes:

- change the path to blend file to your own blend file
- If you're not on Mac, use the Windows or Linux path to Blender executable, as appropriate, e.g. simply blender, on Ubuntu, perhaps)

The above approach appears to work without needing to set the context. No need to select the appropriate object, nor properties space, prior to running. (unlike for baking fluids for example)